# C# Parallel for slowdown

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I don't understand why does the second part (linear for with parallel for of 100 items) always executes faster that a parallel for of 500 items directly? Method1 is a call to an onnx model, but I am not sure if it matters. I am passing the same input to the model.

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Parallel.For(0, 500, i => 
        {
            Method1()
        });
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            Parallel.For(0, 100, i =>
            {
                Method1();
            });
        }
        
        sw.Stop();
```

Comment: Please use a benchmarking library like [benchmark .net](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet)

Comment: What happens in `Method1();`?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski it's a call to a tensor flow model

Comment: Parallel does not execute everything at once... Only a certain amount of items at once. There is a max thread which you can change. Default is I think 4 threads at once.

Comment: Swap tests in code, and you'll be surprised.

Comment: How much faster? Can you share the metrics?

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code. It is pretty much guaranteed that difference come dues to what `Method1` is doing (and in particular if there is any throttling on number of parallel calls). For pure CPU-bound calls you should see zero differences (till you have more than 100-core CPU, but even than difference will be other way around). Please also include CPU load numbers when [edit] the post.

Answer (score -1):

First execution of a code block is generally bound to run slower e.g. because
JIT-compiling may take place here and not occur in the second and all following runs.
Also the code you execute in Method1 might have some internal caching optimizations, e.g. if you query files, the second run is always faster then the first because Windows (or the HD) does some internal caching here (just as an example).

Also perhaps the second code doesn't actually run parallel because it only has 100 cycles, and the first has 500. The TPL might consider 100 cycles to be to little to partition, but 500 is worth it. Then the first loop will have all the overhead you get with parallelism while the 2nd might actually run sequentially which might be faster if the costs of the TPL-overhead are higher.